# Vim - indent with spaces in Python

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I've been using Vim for a while heard people saying indent with spaces is a better practice when programming in Python so I configured my .vimrc as below:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.java,*.cpp,*.c,*.h,*.md,*.html,*.css,*.js
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=120 |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix |
```

Everything works well so far. **But I noticed unlike other editors for example vscode or sublime. Vim does not keep the indent in a line gap between code.**

The cursor will indent itself when I hit `enter` but if I leave that line blank when I return to that line the cursor will appear at the beginning of the line.

Here is an example (@ as cursor):

```py
Class RandomClass:
    code... # 1) hit <enter> and change line
    @ # 2) cursor will appear in here. auto indented. good 3) now hit <enter> again and leave this as a line gap
    code... # 4) code something and 5) return back to the line gap

    # 6) now the cursor '@' would appear at the beginning of the line without indentation
```

Is this what it suppose to be?

Comment: not a vim expert, but why do you have ```autoindent``` commented out? Seems like that could be the reason

Comment: I believe that's just a stack overflow formatting thing. I've edited it so it does not look at being commented out. thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this works for Python, but for most languages you can press `cc` on an empty line to get into insert mode with the cursor already indented.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-the-correct-indentation-level-without-quiting-insert-m for starting insert at the right indentation on a line where Vim stripped it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this what it suppose to be?

Yes, if there is no code on the line, then there is no need to indent it.

Comment: Thanks. I also followed the tips in this [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-the-correct-indentation-level-without-quiting-insert-m) and there is a work around config I can add to .vimrc which I found in [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Get_the_correct_indent_for_new_lines_despite_blank_lines#:~:text=Often%20when%20you%20enter%20a,that%20line%20with%20any%20indent.)